# Using Facebook-iOS-SDK (4.0.1) result.isCancelled is set when using a browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios8

I'm using Facebook-iOS-SDK (4.0.1) for logging in with custom button. I'm implementing the following code

```
- (IBAction)fbButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Process error
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
    } else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
            // Do work
            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {


                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:nil]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result2, NSError *error) {

                     if (!error) {
                         NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result2);
                     }
                 }];
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

}

if I have facebook app installed on a device then the code works fine. When I do not have facebook app installed, then the facebook is opened in a browser. Here, 'result.isCancelled' is set to 'YES' and I do not get a required result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation];
}
```

is required in appDelegate.m

Comment: I can confirm this is the solution. I had a lot of issues until I dug out this. Wish Facebook could handle errors as well.

Comment: still i am getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was different

The following line caused result.isCancelled to always be true... idk why

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"gender"]
```

After changing to this... it worked

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
```

Answer (score 0):

⚫ This function is required in SceneDelegate.swift

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
            return
        }
        let _ = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            UIApplication.shared,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: nil,
            annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }
```