# swift ios facebook login nothing happens when clicking on launch FB app using the new login screen

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I noticed when loging in with Facebook in my app there is a new button that says "Login in using the facebook app" but when I click on it nothing happens. But if I click on "login using email" it works. But why wont the facebook app launch? I have it installed on my phone

code for login:

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){

                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!

                if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                    return
                }

                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                }
            }
        }
```

Pic of the login screen:
[image]

Btn1 says: `"Login using the facebook app"`

Btn2 says: `"Login using phone or email"`

If I click on **Btn2** I get to fill in my email click on login then accept and everything works. But if I click on **Btn1** nothing happens beside the view closing and I end up back at the loginscreen of my app

Also, Keychain sharing is enabled.

**Update:**

This gets called:

```
if (result?.isCancelled)! {
     return
}
```

But I have no clue why `isCancelled` would get triggered?

Comment: Can you set breakpoints and note if it makes it into the Facebook login method, and if it does, what line does it stop working? Do you get a result? What is it?

Comment: @KaylaGalway I found out that ```isCancelled``` gets called. I have updated my question

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667307/using-facebook-ios-sdk-4-0-1-result-iscancelled-is-set-when-using-a-browser

Comment: thanks @KaylaGalway